# How to make a single line systabcontrol32 that scrolls but doesn't show a scrollbar

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi I'm creating a `systabcontrol32` control with the `TCS_SINGLELINE` style when I resize my window so the tab won't fit an up-down control appears that should allow me to scroll so I can see all the tabs.

The thing is that the up-down buttons don't seem to work unless I add a the `WS_HSCROLL` property to the tab control witch makes it ugly as hell. It could be cool if the up-down could scroll the tabs without need to add the scrollbar (even more since the scroll bar doesn't seem to work, it just sits there and I can't click it).

Answer (score 1):

I've used tab controls in an application that have TCS_SINGLELINE, and it seems to work fine: if there are more tabs than the space allows, little left/right buttons appear to the right, allowing the tab to scroll. It should "just work".

Can you post some example code? Or try to put together a minimal application demonstrating it not working? A quick test here indicates that it seems to be okay (at least, on Windows XP here).